# How to show that $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be the function on $[0, 1]$ given by:

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & : x \neq \frac{1}{2}\\\\
2 & : x = \frac{1}{2}\end{array}
\right.$$

Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable and compute $\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Hint: for each $\epsilon > 0$, find a
partition $P$ so that $U_P (f) − L_P(f) \leq \epsilon$.

So I understand that I have to show that $U_P (f ) = L_P(f )$ to show that it is integrable, but I have no idea where to start. What partition do I pick and how do I even come about picking it?

Also as far as the integral, I figure that it is 1, although I'm not sure if I am right. Since it is a single point ($x = \frac{1}{2} $) where the function is not uniformly continuous, does it change the area as a whole?

Comment: $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary  You have to show this is true no matter what $\varepsilon$ you are handed. It's $P$ that you get to choose, not $\varepsilon$

Comment: Once you prove that is integrable.... we can see that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x) dx +\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f(x) dx$ and these are straight forward to calculate

Comment: so how do I pick my P?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: @Ricky actually draw a picture of the function and then partition the space in the MOST natural way.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the partition $P_n = (0, {1 \over 2}-{1 \over n}, {1 \over 2}-{1 \over n}, 1)$. Then
$L(f,P_n) = 1$, $U(f,P_n) = 1+{2 \over n}$.

It follows that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 1$.

Comment: You are assuming Riemann integrability and finding the value of the integral. OP asks you to prove integrability.

Comment: I don't follow your comment. I have exhibited a partition for which the upper & lower sums are arbitrarily close which is tantamount to showing integrability.